# sql- exceeding variable size in a exec?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I inherited some partially complete sql code that I can't get to work.

it accesses multiple databases, so it first searches for proper database using a userID number, then inserts that database name into a query. the part i'm having a problem with (extremely abbreviated) is...

```
DECLARE @sql AS VARCHAR(8000)  
    SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO ['+@DatabaseName+'].dbo.[customer]  
                  ( -- containing about 200 columns. )  
                VALUES(...)'  
PRINT @sql  
EXEC(@sql)
```

i would get errors in the middle of a column name, sometimes saying it's expecting a parenthesis or quote. i started deleting white space so that, ie, [first name],[last name] were on the same line and not two different lines and that would get me a little further down the query. i don't have much more white spaces i can delete and i'm only just getting into the Values(...) portion of it. the weird thing is. i copy and pasted just the columns portion and put it into Word and it comes up as being only about 3,000 characters, including white space.

am i missing something?
if it means anything, i'm running microsoft sql server 2005, and using the sql server management studio for editing

thanks!

Comment: "am i missing something?" Proper capitalization ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See here: [SQL Server: When 8000 Characters Is Not Enough](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/sql-2000-when-8000-characters-is-not-eno) for a couple of solutions

Comment: in your link there was a section on how to divide the query into several pieces, with some playing around that ended up being my solution. created a @sql1 @sql2 and @sql3 each as a varchar(max) and then broke up the insert(...) and value(...) among those 3. finished it off with a print @sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3  then a  exec(@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3) to execute it.   Thanks SQLMenace, sorry i didn't get to this sooner.

Answer (score 1):

> extremely abbreviated

Well, that doesn't really help since you have likely *abbreviated away* the cause of the issue.

If I were to guess, I have seen cases where NCHAR or CHAR variables/columns were involved.  These expand to their full length when used in string concatenation and it will cause the final statement to be too long.

For what it's worth for style or otherwise, use NVarchar(Max) always for SQL Server 2005 and onwards.  In fact, that is the expected type if you use sp_executesql.

If you check for fixed-width N/CHAR columns and switch to nvarchar(max), you may see the problem go away.

**EDIT**: Test showing NVarchar(Max) holding well in excess of 8000 bytes.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

-- this CTE sets up the columns, 1 as field1, 2 as field2 etc
-- it creates 2000 columns
;with CTE(n, t) AS (
    select 1, convert(nvarchar(max),'1 as field1')
    union all
    select n+1, convert(nvarchar(max),RIGHT(n, 12) + ' as field'+RIGHT(n, 12))
    from cte
    where N < 2000)
select @sql = coalesce(@sql+',','') + t
from CTE
option (maxrecursion 2000)   -- needed, the default of 100 is not nearly enough

-- add the SELECT bit to make a proper SQL statement
set @sql = 'select ' + @sql

-- check the length : 33786
select LEN(@sql)

-- check the content
print @sql

-- execute to get the columns
exec (@sql)
```

Comment: from the link SQLMenance gave me, i split the insert(...) values(...) into 3 variables of max size and executed it from there.  the problem was encountered though before i even reached the values(...), just the table columns with a carraige return and some spacing was too much to fit in a single sql variable of max size.

Comment: are you sure? `too much to fit in a single sql variable of max size.` You have a sql query of over 2 GB in datalength? By `max size` you mean varchar(max) right?

Comment: "sql variable of max size." ..."varchar(max) right?"  -yes, variable, not query. the listing of column names were too long themselves to fit in one variable, hence me first trying to delete whitespace and seeing i was exceeding the limit of the size of that variable.

Comment: @dave any comments on the test in the edited answer? I have never had a problem with nvarchar(max) `NOT` being able to hold anything less than 2 GB of data

Comment: ok, you have a proof of concept, congrats. All i know is it would not work in my situation, for whatever reason i would get errors that i had incorrect syntax in the middle of a column name, i would delete some blank spaces before that column and that error would now be further down the line on another column name. i have a solution that works, i'm done. there's no point in arguing the matter. thanks for your thought and wisdom in the matter.

Comment: @dave - Please don't take this personally and be aware that questions on S-O are open to all as an evolving Wiki. I just wanted to make sure to present that the length of the SQL statement in and of itself cannot be the problem. While we will never see your full SQL on S-O, it has to be said the problem is not with the variable at all.

Comment: ok, then why would i get an error in the middle of a, ie. [column name],  telling me it's expecting a '  at the point [colu     then i delete two characters of blank space before that column and it now says error at [column   ?

Comment: I can't see your whole SQL block so I can't comment. I only comment on the part I know for sure works. `There is absolutely no reason why you would need vc(max) + vc(max) + vc(max) to get it working.`

Answer (score 0):

Use an nvarchar(max) datatype for @sql.

Comment: Nvarchar(max) is only 4000 characters, same memory limit but with unicode characters, compared to 8000 of a regular varchar(max). SQLMenace is right. Your variable can't hold all the characters of your query so it is being cut off in the middle. When it prints it out you should see this, are you not seeing this behavior?

Comment: @GluedHands - It is far more likely that what you are seeing is the print output being truncated than any limitation of `nvarchar(max)`! It can hold 2GB of data if sufficient memory is available. Each nchar character is 2 bytes you do the maths!